# count certain values of a field in Crystal Reports

Tags: .net, crystal-reports

I'm fairly new to Crystal Reports, so maybe this is pretty basic but here goes..

I have a field where the value can be Y or N. At the bottom of my report I want to show the amount of Y of this field from the above records.

Example:

```
Name      Field 1 
=====     ========
pers1     Y
pers2     N
pers3     Y
TOTAL     2
```

Anyone has a clue how to get this done? 
Many Thanks for your time!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My approach woule be:

1. Create a formula `@Caclculate` and write below code.

   ```
   if Field1='Y'
   then 1
   else 0
   ```

Place the formula adjacent to `Field 1` and supress.

2 . Now take the sum of the `@Calculate` and place it in footer.

Take sum by `Right Click field calculate-->Insert --> summary`

Edit----------------------------------------------------------------------------------

one more  apporach.. try this:

you can use running total.

1. In field to summarize take `Field1` and take `count` as option to summarize.
2. In evaluate use option formula, In that write below condition.

   ```
   if(Field1='Y')
   then true
   else false
   ```
3. In reset use option never.

Comment: I tried this, but it returns ,00 Any thoughts on how to get rid of this?
Your idea looks great btw!

Comment: where dod you place the summary? if you place in footer then your won't be zero

Comment: I put it in the footer.. But my formula return ,00 also.. so the problem is in the function I guess

Comment: no formula will work for sure.. where did you place the formula ? also are there are `Y` in the database?

Comment: this is the formula
if  {GOKData.NedMoeder} = 'J'  then 1 else 0
I put it in the column where the GOKData.NedMoeder field is..

Comment: thats fine... I would suggest to check 2 things... `1. Is J case sensitive` and `Does J exits in database?`

Answer (score 0):

Your "Y" and "Parse" is seprate column ? I think separate in your question, so simply use Running total as descrive link or you can use summarize field.

put a running total field and sum of this.

http://victoriayudin.com/2009/11/25/running-totals-in-crystal-reports/

http://crystalreportsblog.com/crystal-reports-running-totals/

Answer (score 0):

Create a formula field:

```
// {@Has_Y}
If {table.Field 1}="Y" Then 1 Else 0
```

Add a summarized field:

- Insert > Summary...
- Substitute `{@Has_Y} for`Last Year's Sales'

[image]

Note: If it makes it easier, you can add `{@Has_Y}` to the `details` section, but it isn't required for the summarized field to work correctly.